# single thread loadbalance UDP traffic on several 1G NIC's gets ~1.1GB overall on windows 2012/2016

Tags: windows, winsock, udpclient

Simple **single thread** app send UDP traffic over 2 or 3 NIC's to send 2GB or 3GB traffic.
on same PC, **Windows 10 success to send 1GB per NIC**, while on windows server 2012/2016 gets only:

- ~550Mbps per NIC when sending to 2 NIC's.
- ~380Mbps per NIC when sending to 3 NIC's.
- ~270Mbps per NIC when sending to 4 NIC's.

**Set SO_SNDBUF to 1 on windows 10 give same performance as Windows 2016/2012**

**It look like Windows sever skip socket buffer(set with SO_SNDBUF) and write it direct to the NIC** Will windows 10 write always to sock buffer.

Update the code to be multi-threaded(1 thread per socket) and I have get 1Gbps for each NIC on 2016 as well.

Test code from https://www.binarytides.com/udp-socket-programming-in-winsock/  with same changes:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib") //Winsock Library

#define SERVER "127.0.0.1"  //ip address of udp server
#define BUFLEN 63*1024  //Max length of buffer
#define PORT 8888   //The port on which to listen for incoming data
struct socket_data
{
    SOCKET s;
    struct sockaddr_in si_other;
    std::string ip;
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int slen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char message[64 * 1024];
    std::vector<socket_data> sd;
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (2 > argc)
    {
        printf("please provide list of destinations IP.\n");
        printf("For example:\n %ls 22.22.22.255 11.11.11.255 12.12.12.255\n", std::experimental::filesystem::path(argv[0]).filename().c_str());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    for (size_t i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        socket_data tmp;
        tmp.ip = argv[i];
        sd.push_back(tmp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < BUFLEN; ++i)
    {
        message[i] = i;
    }
    //Initialise winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("Failed. Error Code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialised.\n");

    //create socket
    for (int i = 0; i < sd.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ((sd[i].s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("socket() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        //setup address structure
        memset((char *)&sd[i].si_other, 0, sizeof(sd[i].si_other));
        sd[i].si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
        sd[i].si_other.sin_port = htons(PORT);
        sd[i].si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr(sd[i].ip.c_str());
        int sendbuff = 20*1024*1024;
        setsockopt(sd[i].s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*)&sendbuff, sizeof(sendbuff));
    }


    //start communication
    while (1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sd.size(); ++i) {
            //send the message
            if (sendto(sd[i].s, message, BUFLEN - 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sd[i].si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d", WSAGetLastError());
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        closesocket(sd[i].s);
    }
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Network interface card.

Comment: You need to provide more information about the execution environments.  Are the two tests run on the same computer (dual boot)?

Comment: I have test it on 3 computers(2 servers and 1 pc), Same computer, no dual boot, install win 10 test and install 2016 test. I am pretty  sure it related to Windows 2016/2012 some performance tuning. I have change this test to use multi-thread so 1 thread per connection and I have get 1Gbps for eatch.

Comment: If you don't eliminate the environmental variables due to the different hardware and conditions, we can only guess.

Comment: @M.A Please explain what is missing. I use same PC same computer, no dual boot, install win 10 test with provided code and get 1Gbps for every nic(about 3Gbps for 3 NIC's). Then install 2016 test with provided code and get 350Gbps for every nic(about 1.1Gbps for 3 NIC's). Same test done on 3 different computers(and different vendors).

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue on linux and I get 1Gbps for every NIC with the code below.
For windows 2016/2012 I have managed to solve this issue using connected socket. I use ACE_SOCK_CODgram but I sure using same code above with connect will work(ACE_SOCK_CODgram do connect).